# Proving that $f(x)= \log |x|^2$ is in $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis

I am trying to prove that $f(x)= \log |x|^2$ is in $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^2 $

So I take a compact set $K$ in $ \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\} $ and pass to polar coordinates. I guess I can consider $K \subseteq$  the difference of two closed balls of radii $r_1$ and$r_2 $so that I can integrate over the radius from r_1 to r_2 and make the inner radius r_1 go to 0. Is my approach correct?
$$\int_K |f(x) |dx=\int_K |\log (r^2) |rdrd\theta = 4\pi \int_{r_1}^{r_2} |\log r|rdr$$

I am stuck at this point, can you please help me finish it? I don't know how to deal with the absolute value and the singularity at 0

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean $\log (|x|^2)$ not $(\log |x|)^2$?

Comment: @gist076923 Yes the first one

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is right! It suffices to check whether the integral is finite if $K = B_{1}[0]$ (closed unit ball at origin) since we expect the integrand to blow up at origin. The integral over this ball is simplified as following: $$ \int_{B_1[0]} \log|x|^2 dx = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{\partial B_r(0)} \log|x|^2 d \sigma dr = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{\partial B_1(0)}r \log(r^2)  d \sigma dr = 4\pi\int_{0}^{1}r \log{r}dr$$
which is simply $-\pi$,  therefore $f$ is locally integrable. Observe that $|\log|x|^2| = - \log|x|^2 $ for $x \in B_1[0]$.

Comment: Why does it suffice to check for a unit ball? My compact set might be bigger and then the absolute value does not have a constant sign

Comment: Notice that away from a neighbourhood of origin, the function f is continuous, so the integral over those regions will be finite.